# XML CHild node iteration in Pentaho

Tags: xml, loops, etl, pentaho, kettle

I have an **XML** file which has data in format:

```
<LineHeader>
  <LineItem LineNumber="1">
    <Product SKU="99991L" DespatchQuantity="70">
      <Item Type="EANCode">0821793005795</Item>
      <SKUDescription1>HTC SNAP SYST</SKUDescription1>
      <SKUDescription2 />
      <SerialNumberHeader>
        <SerialNumber>358991022404733</SerialNumber>
        <SerialNumber>358991022404808</SerialNumber>
      </SerialNumberHeader>
    </Product>
  </LineItem>
  <LineItem LineNumber="2">
    <Product SKU="37099M" DespatchQuantity="50">
      <Item Type="EANCode">0843163067660</Item>
      <SKUDescription1>RIM KEPLER SYST</SKUDescription1>
      <SKUDescription2 />
      <SerialNumberHeader>
        <SerialNumber>353933040011632</SerialNumber>
        <SerialNumber>353933042759923</SerialNumber>
      </SerialNumberHeader>
    </Product>
  </LineItem>
</LineHeader>
```

Now I want output to be a text file with column names and records like these:

```
LineItem 
LineNumber  Product SKU EANCode         SKUDescription1   SerialNumber
1           99991L      821793005795    HTC SNAP SYST     358991022404808
1           99991L      821793005795    HTC SNAP SYST     358991022434987
1           99991L      821793005795    HTC SNAP SYST     358991022435505
2           37099M      843163067660    RIM KEPLER SYST   353933040011632
2           37099M      843163067660    RIM KEPLER SYST   353933042759923
```

Output data should look like the above table. 
How can we achieve the looping in **pentaho**.

Comment: thanks miko for editing..yes the output data should look like that. i have very les JAVA experience as i am more of a ETL developer. Can anyone suggest how to achieve the above feat using PENTAHO? i know abt getXML and STAX transformations, but not sure what to do with them. May we need to use a java class/java expression for looping. Please sugget.

Comment: Anyone knows how to achieve it through pentaho transformations? it is like i am able to choose xpath nodes, but when i redirect the output in a flat file, "serial number" column entries appear to be placed in one cell. i want that column to save all serial numbers in seperate lines vertically..

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you'd like one line of output for each serial number (the question shows five output lines but I *think* you mean four):

In the `Get XML Data` step

`Content` tab

Set Loop XPath to `/LineHeader/LineItem/Product/SerialNumberHeader`

`Fields` tab

```
Name            XPath                 Element
LineNumber      ../../../LineNumber   Attribute
Product SKU     ../../SKU             Attribute
EANCode         ../../Item            Node
SKUDescription1 ../../SKUDescription1 Node
SerialNumber    .                     Node
```

Will output

```
LineNumber Product SKU           EANCode SKUDescription1 SerialNumber
1          99991L  0821793005795 HTC     SNAP SYST       358991022404733
1          99991L  0821793005795 HTC     SNAP SYST       358991022404808
2          37099M  0843163067660 RIM     KEPLER SYST     353933040011632
2          37099M  0843163067660 RIM     KEPLER SYST     353933042759923
```

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, the basic problem here is that ETL tools are designed to work with tabular data, not hierarchical data. Trying to do this is like forcing a square peg into a round hole. You might be able to get it done once or twice, but it won't be pretty, it will break easily, and it certainly won't be reusable.

There is an example transform in the samples directory of using a StAX input step to do this. It's called 'XML Input Stream (StAX) Test 4 - Hierarchies.ktr'. You'll note however that the PDI people used a UDJC to build the hierarchies.

I've messed around with your example for a while now, and I can't find an elegant way to do it with transforms at all. I think scripting is your best bet.

EDIT --

You know, this might be a good application for a custom control. One that would map an XML document to the tabular data like you want for your output. I suspect this is a common problem; I wonder if Matt & Co. have plans for anything like that.